# How to select cast an enum as string, and get it's name instead or it's ordinal in JPQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hql, jpql

```
public enum En {
   A, B, C;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Table {
   @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
   En en;
   ...
}
```

`SELECT CAST(t.en AS string) FROM Table t`

It returns me the ordinal value of the enum: "1", "2", "3".

Is there a way i can cast it directly to the enum's name() correspondent instead? i.e. "A", "B", "C"

Comment: If you change the EnumType of the field to `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` the cast function will return the names.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no guaranteed way to do this. If you are using ordinal mappings, the SQL side of things does not know about the enum names. One thing you could do, which is painful though, is to write out a case when expression `case when t.en = En.A then 'A' when t.en = En.B then 'B' when t.en = En.C then 'C' else null end`. Why do you need this? You could just fetch the enum value and transform this in Java.